# Ref to bibitem by direct command, not by \cite

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibitem

For some reason, I need to ref to the name declared in `\bibitem{name}` directly by some command, not by `\cite`. It appears to be possible by label`\b@name` (surrounded by`\makeaatletter` and `\makeatother`). However, it does not work when `name` contains some special characters like `_`, which are allowed in bibitem names and can be reffered by `\cite`. Here is a little example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

     \makeatletter[\b@Name,\b@NameOne,\b@NameTwo]\makeatother %works
     \cite{Name_} %works

     \makeatletter[\b@Name_]\makeatother %does not work


     \begin{thebibliography}{1}

          \bibitem{Name}

          \bibitem{Name_}

          \bibitem{NameOne}

          \bibitem{NameTwo}

     \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I am almost sure that LaTeX produces for `Name_` the command more complicated than `\b@Name_`, because `_` has special meaning (subindex in math mode). I tried to guess the command for `Name_`, also used 'tracingmacros', but without success.

So, the question is: how to determ command like `\b@Name` for the name with underbar `_`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you need direct access to the labels: this feels like an 'xy' issue (you want to do x, you think y is the way to do that).

Comment: One aim is to cite to several items in the same pair of brackets. See example in the question.

Comment: But that's a standard feature of `\cite`: `\cite{fooA,fooB}`.

Comment: Yes, that is the standard feature. There are some packages that do additional magic like sorting the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will also work at the first compilation (when the commands are not yet in the aux and so not defined. `\UseName` requires a rather current LaTeX. In older systems you can use `\csname b@Name\endcsname`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\UseName{b@Name}, \UseName{b@NameOne}, 
\UseName{b@NameTwo}, \UseName{b@Name_}


     \begin{thebibliography}{1}

          \bibitem{Name}

          \bibitem{Name_}

          \bibitem{NameOne}

          \bibitem{NameTwo}

     \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant the second (and further) compilation. The problem is that I don't know this csname which is defined by `\bibitem` and used by `\cite`.

Comment: Did you try my code?

Comment: Have tried right now - it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Besides making `at` a `letter`, you need to do the same with `_`:

```
\catcode`\_11
```

Full example (where I am using `{`group`}` to restore `_`):

```
\documentclass{book}
%\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \makeatletter[\b@Name,\b@NameOne,\b@NameTwo]\makeatother %works
    cite: \cite{Name_} %works
 
   The solution:
   {\makeatletter\catcode`\_11    [\b@Name_]}% precent here kills the space, do you want a space here?
  
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{1}
        
        \bibitem{Name}
        
        \bibitem{Name_}
        
        \bibitem{NameOne}
        
        \bibitem{NameTwo}
        
    \end{thebibliography}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, catcode works, thanks! Of course, catcode of underbar `_` has to be back to its native 8.

It is strange why it works (as well as `\csname ... \endcsname`). I was sure that LaTeX checks characters in item name by their codes (unicode, e.g.), not by catcode.

Comment: Of course it works. There are circumstances where it will not. How to know when? One has to understand workings or TeX and what catcode is used for. Have you heard about TeX's mouth, stomach and so on? TeX eats the characters of the input files consecutively. At the moment moment TeX takes a char, its catcode decides what the character will be for all time during the digestion. Therefore it works. And csname makes TeX to ignore the catcodes (until it eats \endcsname).

Comment: Yes, I've read about TeX's stomach (allegory of Donald Knuth). Of course, after redefining catcode, all characters are treated as a letter (of catcode 11). However, I expected that the macros `\bibitem` and `\cite` (maybe, along with other ones) analyze the characters by their code (e.g.,code of space symbol is 32, code of 'a' is 97).  Example about food: when someone are buying, e.g. , buckwheat porridge, he/she check if it is namely buckwheat porridge, and would be unsatisfacted if it is merely cereals.

Comment: 1/2 Macros may do the things, but you are after reading a macro name backslash-b-@-N-a-...  and this fun is going on only until you find something having catcode different from 11. More details: eating backslash. interpretting backslash: it has special catcode which means we should read a macro name. Eating b. It is a letter. So the macro is not like \, or \- but like \abcde. Need more letters. Eating @. What is its catcode?

Comment: 2/2  Letter, fine, the macro name starts with b@. (If this is not a letter, the fun is over, and macro `\b` is expanded). Eating N. Letter. And so on until `_` is eaten and everything decided on its catacode.  (Not letter => macro name is b@Name. Letter=>macro name starts `b@Name_` and we read more letters, if there are any.